# What action to take for questions about debugging ChatGPT generated code?

Tags: discussion

I have seen some questions recently posting code generated by chatGPT and asking for debugging. Some of them are not even real code and the OP doesn't spend time on researching or having enough background to run the code. I saw ChatGPT answers are banned [Accounts farming rep using chatGPT](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/724/accounts-farming-rep-using-chatgpt) but not questions?

Comment: if you see such question please flag them.